# Marathi Font Support for Textview in Android

Tags: android, fonts

I have a widget layout containing textview. I want to set marathi text to that textview. 
I am trying ticker widget which shows marathi news on screen. the problem is i am unable to set marathi font to remoteview. Any Help? Thanks in advance

Edited:

Here is My code

```
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout); 
// Set the text 
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_marqee, stringBuffer);
```

this is my remoteview inflating widget_layout. And this layout contains textview which i am using as a ticker.  I want to set devnagari font to remoteview. Any help?

Comment: Rakesh, if you have Home Screen Widget Then custom fonts not allowed to use in Home Screen so either use inbuild fonts or generate a bitmap for ImageView.

Answer (score 3):

As Devanagari fonts are not supported by Android, you can still give that support to your Application.

For Marathi font copy font file to your asset folder. then use the following code.

```
 TextView text_view = new TextView(this);
 Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "MarathiFont.ttf");
 text_view.setTypeface(font);
 text_view.setText("मराठी");
```

the same way u can give support for hindi....

Comment: RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
     .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
     R.layout.widget_layout);
   // Set the text
   remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_marqee, stringBuffer); this is my remoteview. I ant to set devnagari font to remoteview.Any help?

Comment: pls add the code in the question...i cannot read it in the comment

Comment: as Sajid Shaikh said you can only render your font onto a
Bitmap in your process, and then push it across RemoteViews.

Answer (score 0):

For this you will have to Get a MarathiFont.ttf file, then

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/MarathiFont.ttf");
```

and then :

```
text.setTypeFace(tf);
```

Comment: Thank u..i downloaded kirana.ttf file..and now it is working..Can you pls tell me how it can work on simulator???

Comment: Yea it works the same way, you dont have to do anything else.

Comment: But for me it is not working in 2.2 or 2.3 devices also..it is only showing some squares there..but in android 4.0 devices, it is coming fine..Please help..

Comment: I trie on 2.2 and 2.3 devices as well as 3.0 tablet

Answer (score 0):

Dude its so simple Just use follwing line of code

```
TextView info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/georgia.ttf"); 
info.setTypeface(face);
```

Place your font in assets in fonts folder. Work karel. Thanks

Comment: RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout); // Set the text remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.txt_marqee, stringBuffer); this is my remoteview. I ant to set devnagari font to remoteview.Any help?

Comment: Because widgets live in other processes, they can only use system
typefaces, and not additional fonts that might be internal to your
package.  One way around this would be to render your font onto a
Bitmap in your process, and then push it across RemoteViews.  http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/html/android-developers@googlegroups.com/2009-06/msg00211.html

Answer (score 0):

First up all you should add the marathi font (ttf) in devices.  Below is the `adb` command for adding the font.

> adb su push .ttf /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf

Then use this font  for display.

Answer (score 0):

1)download marathi fonts from website as follows:

http://www.angelfire.com/pop/top4/fonts/

2)apply following code:

```
TextView info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/your font.ttf"); 
info.setTypeface(face);
```