# Display marathi font (Indian regional language) in android app

Tags: android, regional

I have been trying to show marathi font using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940199/marathi-font-support-for-textview-in-android) in my app. But some how its not working for me. It gives no error but does not show any font in text view. I came to know about internationalization concept when I first tried to do this.

Comment: have put your otf ,ttf file in assests.

Comment: I have put the link. I am doing the same. and , I have put the ttf file in src/fonts/font.tff earlier that was in res folder. But didnt work either way. Do i also have to install the font on the computer system?

Comment: Put your otf ,ttf file in **assests**.

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView info=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/FontAwesome.otf");
info.setTypeface(face); 
info.setText("TypeFace");
```

[image]

Comment: Please paste your code here how you do it? you might be missing somthing